# Applying to PhD programmes in multiple universities

Tags: phd, application

I want to apply for a PhD. I applied to 2 universities before and got rejected. Is it OK to send my PhD proposal to multiple universities at the same time in the hope that I get approval from one of them?

Comment: I applied to ~40 positions to get a PhD :/

Comment: Back when I was applying, there were no personal computers.  So I had to type each cover letter individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is OK and normal to apply to multiple schools.

But you should tailor your PhD proposal for each application so that you explain why you would like to study in the specific environment offered by that school (e.g. particular academics you would like to work for, courses you'd like to take etc.).

Answer (score 12):

Yes.

In the United States, it is expected that applicants are applying to many schools at the same time.

I applied to around 10 simultaneously, for example.

Comment: It should be pointed out that in the US, the synchronization of applications results from most graduate schools operating on a similar annual admissions schedule.